Warning "DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead."
Below is the error I'm facing. Can anyone help in resolving it?
I want to run it without any errors.
Starting project at /home/user/Desktop/react-native/aroa
(node:31645) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:31645) [DEP0044] DeprecationWarning: The `util.isArray` API is deprecated. Please use `Array.isArray()` instead.
Starting Metro Bundler
warning: Bundler cache is empty, rebuilding (this may take a minute)
(node:31645) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(node:31645) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
█ ▄▄▄▄▄ █ ██▀▀█▀▄▀█ ▄▄▄▄▄ █
█ █   █ █  ▀█ ▀█ ██ █   █ █
█ █▄▄▄█ █▀  █▄▀▀▄▀█ █▄▄▄█ █
█▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█▄█ ▀▄█▄▀ █▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█
█▄ ▀▀  ▄▀██▄█▄▀▄ ▄▀█ ▀▄▄ ▄█
██▄▀  ▀▄█▀ ▄█▀██▄▄ ▀▀   ▀██
█▀█▀▄▀▄▄█▄▀▀▄▀█▄ █▀▄ ▀▄ ▀██
█████▄▄▄  ▄█ ▄██   ███ ▀███
█▄▄█▄█▄▄█▀▀▄█▄▀▄▀ ▄▄▄ ▀ ▄▄█
█ ▄▄▄▄▄ █▀▀ █▀█▀▀ █▄█ ▀▀▀▀█
█ █   █ █▄▀ ▄▀▄ ▀ ▄ ▄▄▀   █
█ █▄▄▄█ █▀ ▄ ▄ ▄▄▄▄ ▀█▀▀ ██
█▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█▄███▄▄█████▄▄▄▄▄▄█

› Metro waiting on exp://10.20.30.95:8081
› Scan the QR code above with Expo Go (Android) or the
Camera app (iOS)

› Web is waiting on http://localhost:8081

› Using Expo Go
› Press s │ switch to development build

› Press a │ open Android
› Press w │ open web

› Press j │ open debugger
› Press r │ reload app
› Press m │ toggle menu
› Press o │ open project code in your editor

› Press ? │ show all commands

Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.



Please ensure you are using the node's LTS(long-term support) version.
You can validate the version here: https://nodejs.org/en (20.13.1) LTS support to use.
If you use the latest node version not the LTS, You will face the above-mentioned problems like depreciation

i tired doing that but still i couldnt fix it

There's little you can do right now about this warning – the ecosystem has modules that depend on punycode which will be deprecated sometime in the future. (As the message says, you can run with --trace-deprecation to see which module(s) are the culprit(s).)

i want to run it with out any errors

For the time being, ignore this warning – it is not an error, and is not a cause for concern.

How do we use trace-deprecation?

@IgorGanapolsky node --trace-deprecation, or if you're not directly running node, set the NODE_OPTIONS=--trace-deprecation environment variable.

Warning: don't "Ignore that warning."  My dev team recently "ignored that warning" right into a massive problem that took us a very long time to fix.  Maybe you mean ignore this particular warning, but ignoring warnings in general is not (necessarily) a good idea.

@Raydot Yes, ignoring all warnings is not a good idea, but ignoring this warning is, because there's little you can do aside from sending PRs to upstream packages. I'll clarify the answer.

@AKX you heard exactly what I was saying.  Thanks.

its not a big thing just ignore it, it won't cause any issues it's a internal expo thing and deprecated means just an older unsupported version so it would still work as expected, no worries!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

For NextJs who are having this issue :
Install the module-alias package,run this command:
npm install module-alias

Then Update your next.config.mjs
import moduleAlias from 'module-alias'

moduleAlias.addAlias('punycode', 'punycode/')

const nextConfig = {


};
export default nextConfig;

If you're using typescript, add the path to your tsconfig.json
  {
"compilerOptions": {
"paths": {
"punycode": ["./node_modules/punycode/"]
}
}

source : https://github.com/mathiasbynens/punycode.js/issues/137
